# Missing word for Sphinx recognizing

Tags: java

I am trying to add words for french in the cmudict.0 file. I have added three words but now I get the following error.

```
    Loading...
    07:03.838 WARNING dictionary        Missing word: quatre
               in edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.FastDictionary:getWord-dictionary
    07:03.839 WARNING jsgfGrammar       Can't find pronunciation for Quatre
               in edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.language.grammar.Grammar:createGrammarNode-jsgfGrammar
```

You will see three words, I have added perfectly fine and they work, but when adding "quatre" I get the above error. Here is the Image of the cmudict.0 file

[image]

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787303/cmu-sphinx-nullpointerexception-at-recognizer-allocate

Comment: @gonephishing No, different problem